# Check what item is next to be deleted with delete key press

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a contentEditable area (in Chrome specifically at the moment).

If I capture the delete key press, is it possible to know what the next element or text is that is to be deleted?

What I'm really wanting to test is if the next item to delete is a

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Then I don't want to delete it.

I was looking at treeselection here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Tree_Selection
but wasn't really clear on how to implement it if this is even what I need to be looking at.

Comment: Oh nevermind.  Dumb question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind guys.  This was a dumb question.  All I simply needed to do is see if I'm at the end of the current node, if I am don't do anything.

Sometimes I make things more complicated than they really are.

Something like this worked for me:

```
if(event.keyCode == 46){
 var s = document.getSelection();
 if(s.anchorOffset == s.anchorNode.length){
   return false;    
 }
}
```

Comment: You can accept this answer which removes the question from the unresolved queue....